# How can i make list items clickable on android

Tags: java, persistence.xml

Good day ,please i need to know how to make a list items click able on android..i am developing a bible with 10 versions for my final year project in school and i need to know how i can click on a list items and it woud take me to another page with a list item on it.

Like if i click on genesis , it would take me to the chapters under genesis on another listview layout..

i have been working on this for long and i need to submit my project on Monday unfailingly

i have been writting it for months and have not gotten it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get a positive response here, please show us what you have tried. Consider adding an [MCTRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an ArrayList type to store all the values that you want to give in the list. Then use an ArrayAdapter to put all these list items into the list. That way, all the items will be clickable.

for example-->

```
    public class CreateList extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<String> myList=new ArrayList<String>;
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.createlist);

            myAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>  (CreateList.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList);
            setListAdapter(myAdapter);

 myList.add("genesis");
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

    }
```

you can make your xml file as-->

createlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView 
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps. :)